# Using external javascript code to run a snippet on the Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Is it possible in an external javascript code (for example, a userscript through tampermonkey) to run a code snippet on the Chrome console. For example, `console.log` prints text to the console. Is there some way, like a function `console.eval` or some more complex way where I can run code *on* the console without manually opening it on the given website, but using the original javascript code behind the website or a userscript?

Notes: I use Google Chrome on Windows 10. Preferably this answer should be as generally applicable as possible, but first priority for me is for it to work in my environment.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: what is your end goal? and can you try to use the devtools api via extension or you are restricted to regular javascript from pages?

Comment: There happens to be a snippet of code that works in the console, but not in userscript itself. Very basic DOM retrieval using `querySelector` and then changing a style, but based on the DOM structure (an iframe) the code only works in the console, so if I can run a snippet of code on the console through my userscript, that would be nice. (The page is constantly reloading, so it is impractible to copy-paste a code every time).

Comment: ok, now we have a tottaly different question. now you said you want to a userscript access the dom from internal/external iframe from own/other domain. which of those would it be? internal or external iframe? local or remote? i would recommend opening another question because the answer is so different from the question title, that the next people with the same doubt won't read the question/answers because they would be unrelated.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what I want. I simply want to be able to run a snippet of code on the chrome console from my userscript.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. From what you describe, I would guess that the bug in the non-working code is that it queries its own iframe window instead `window.top`. The code works in the console because it accesses the top window.

Comment: So how can I access it? Either I run something in console (which I want to do through a userscript), or I access the HTML inside the iframe...how do I do that?

Comment: if the page is reloading constantly, the "console" that u think of would also reload??

Comment: @MikeSmith see if my answer helped >:D

Comment: @MikeSmith i repeat i answered the question.. could you please at least check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uk, when i said `if the page is reloading constantly, the "console" that u think of would also reload??`, a lot of us knew about what I'm doing below(if not all of us) but I finally connected it with your question. **Using one tab to control the other tab**

**ONE EDIT**: I used an `interval` to determine if the controlled tab is **CLOSED**(since a certain value *eventually* changes if the tab is **closed for good**)

**HOW TO USE**:

1. Open a tab with the same origin as desired url(but not the constantly reloading site)..

   **eg**: *opening a tab on "https://example.com/404" if desired url is "https://example.com" is the desired url(the constantly reloading one)*
2. In the code snippet I have below, you can put your tab controlling code in the `loadFn` function, where `myWindow` and `this` point to the controlled tab's `window`

   **eg**: *in the `loadFn` function, `myWindow.console.log(1)` or `this.console.log(1)` would both log `1` to the controlled tab's console*

**SECOND EDIT**: I shall explain how it works(and talk about `unloadFn` as you requested in comments)

I use a combination of `unload` and `load` listening to be able to repeatedly send code *`"on reload"`* which is not an event in itself so I had to *create it*. In case I didn't explain myself, I'd go into detail now..

When a page is reloading(or when I'm **JUST SPAWNING** the page, *eg*: `var myWindow=window.open(desiredUrl)`), the `unload` event happens. There's just **one problem** however; every time the page is reloading, all event listeners and any code you put is removed(because *reload unloads to **then** reload*)

The solution is simple: on every `unload`, I set the listners **again**, and since the function would call itself(every time the page unloads), the listeners would successfully be reloaded every time the page reloads(and that is why `loadFn` could run in the other tab after every reload)

**DO NOTE**: You might ask *"why use a `setTimeout` then?"*. Actually it's **quite important**. Without the `setTimeout`, the event listeners **DO NOT GET ADDED**, I think it's because the tab would ignore your commands(since it would be focusing on loading its default stuff(like event listeners for instance)), and `asynchronous programming` does wonders in this case because it will wait until the other stuff are processed(like event handling stuff) **then** run

**SIDE NOTE**: If that's not why `setTimeout` works and *NOT USING* it doesn't, all I know is that without it, it doesn't work, and with it, it works

```
var myWindow=window.open(desiredUrl) //remember to run this code on the same origin as the desiredUrl
function loadFn(){
  //this will happen every time myWindow loads or reloads
  myWindow.alert("It runs in the controlled tab")
  myWindow.console.log("Even in the controlled tab's console it works >:D")
}
function unloadFn(){setTimeout(()=>{
  myWindow.addEventListener('unload',unloadFn)
  myWindow.addEventListener('load',loadFn)
  if(!myWindow.Window){console.warn("myWindow was CLOSED")}
},0)}
myWindow.addEventListener('unload',unloadFn)
//extra thing below to tell if controlled tab is closed >:D
var i=setInterval(()=>{
  //for if controlled tab is closed
  if(!myWindow.document.location){clearInterval(i);console.warn("myWindow was CLOSED")}
},0)
```

Comment: Great solution, just a couple of questions --- what does the unload function do? And second, I want to run code in the console of the constantly reloading page. How do I use the page controlling the reloading page's console to run code? Thanks.

Comment: clarification: run code the controlled page's console

Comment: @MikeSmith I just edited the question trying to answer these questions here.. also if that's to big a read, the comment below explains the `unloadFn` without the context

Comment: The solution is simple: on every `unload`, I set the listners **again**, and since the function would call itself(every time the page unloads), the listeners would successfully be reloaded every time the page reloads(and that is why `loadFn` could run in the other tab after every reload)

Comment: @MikeSmith one more thing.. as for running code on the controlled tab's console, do you mean the equivalent of pasting code in a tab's console then pressing enter? If so, `myWindow.eval(stringVersionOfCopiedCode)` in `loadFn` would do the trick.. also remember that you can treat `myWindow` as the controlled tab's `window`. If what I said didn't help, could you share an example of what you mean by *running code in the controlled page's console*?

Comment: @MikeSmith btw, do you mind saying what url you're trying this out on? because this problem was VERY INTERESTING >:D